# Is there a way to get a PDF out of puppeteer with headings with different levels for accessibility?

Tags: pdf, puppeteer

See this example code:

```
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <h2>World</h2>
```

If I convert this HTML to a PDF using Puppeteer, and then open that PDF with Acrobat Reader and NVDA Screen reader, it reads "Hello heading", "World heading". But for other PDFs NVDA can actually read heading levels, is there a way to do so? For other PDFs it can read "Hello heading level 1", "Hello heading level2".

I have exported the PDF using tags, I also tried changing the html with role="heading" and aria-heading but that didn't help.

Thank you

Comment: What is the puppeteer version

Comment: yes since 0.9.0 version Puppeteer support pdf creation

Comment: Have you tried to use <h1 alt="Heading One">Hello</h1> and tried to see if it will read the alt?